# I'm stuck with this python "wannabe bot". I google it for hours but no success

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to build a bot and make it to run on a raspberry pi 3. On Linux mint it works great but once I moved it to Raspbian I had hard times. I fixed some errors but this one I could find any help over the internet. So I'm posting the code and the error. Any help would be appreciated. Also I uploaded a screenshot with the python directory maybe someone notice something wrong. Please ask any information you need if you think you can help me. Thanks.

The script below :

```
import io
import time
import urllib
from PIL import Image
from random import randint
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
####################################

while True:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://website.com")

    time.sleep(randint(1, 2))

    driver.find_element_by_class_name('login_menu').click()

    time.sleep(randint(1, 3))

    keyAddress = driver.find_element_by_id("login_form")
    keyAddress.send_keys("1NH6N2pT8LMZXz5GFPGgjW85aJ") #acc3

    time.sleep(randint(1, 4))

    password = driver.find_element_by_id("login_password")
    password.send_keys("password")

    time.sleep(randint(1, 3))

    driver.find_element_by_id("login_button").click()


    time.sleep(randint(1, 3))


    driver.find_element_by_class_name("captcha_input").click()

    time.sleep(randint(1, 2))

    driver.get_screenshot_as_file('/home/pi/Desktop/bot/pycap/screenshot.jpg')

    time.sleep(randint(2, 4))

    ####################################################
    ##############CAPTCHA SOLVING MODULE################
    ####################################################

    # Cropping captcha image 
    img = Image.open("screenshot.jpg")

    area = (495, 770, 720, 842)

    imgCropped = img.crop(area)
    imgCropped.save("media.jpg")

    time.sleep(randint(2, 4))

    # Sending image to DBC
    import deathbycaptcha

    # Put your DBC account username and password here.
    # Use deathbycaptcha.HttpClient for HTTP API.
    client = deathbycaptcha.SocketClient('username', 'password')
    try:
        balance = client.get_balance()

        # Put your CAPTCHA file name or file-like object, and optional
        # solving timeout (in seconds) here:
        captcha = client.decode('media.jpg', 60)
        if captcha:
            # The CAPTCHA was solved; captcha["captcha"] item holds its
            # numeric ID, and captcha["text"] item its text.
            print (captcha)
            if captcha:  # check if the CAPTCHA was incorrectly solved
                client.report(captcha["captcha"])
    except deathbycaptcha.AccessDeniedException:
        # Access to DBC API denied, check your credentials and/or balance

    ####################################################

            time.sleep(randint(4, 6))

    sendCaptcha = driver.find_element_by_class_name("captcha_input")
    sendCaptcha.click()

    time.sleep(randint(3, 5))

    solvedCaptcha = (captcha["text"])

    sendCaptcha.send_keys(str(solvedCaptcha))

    time.sleep(randint(1, 3))

    play = driver.find_element_by_id("play_button")
    play.click()

    time.sleep(randint(2, 4))


    driver.quit()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/bot/pycap/looptest.py", line 6, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py3.4.egg/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py3.4.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 34, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py3.4.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .webelement import WebElement
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py3.4.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 40, in <module>
    getAttribute_js = pkgutil.get_data(__package__, 'getAttribute.js').decode('utf8')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/pkgutil.py", line 611, in get_data
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(package)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/util.py", line 81, in find_spec
    fullname = resolve_name(name, package) if name.startswith('.') else name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

And the screenshot :

[image: python directory]

Comment: You posted a lot of code and details, people usually don't want to help debugging. Please, try to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Thanx mate but if someone really wants to help me, it will not only read the code but maybe it will ask for more info. But I'll keep in mind your advice. Thanx alot.

Comment: No, we rarely care about all the code. We care about the smallest possible amount of code that can illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the error output, it says:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

This error usually occurs when somebody forgot to add a return statement to a function/method, as the standard return is `None`, if no return specified.

One line above this error we see where this error results from: it's variable `name` in line 81 of the file */usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/util.py* that for some magic reason is `None`. So, without having this file, it is impossible to know why `name` is `None`.

But though I assume, you didn't write this file, these error might not be your fault, but a problem with this *importlib*, so try to delete and reinstall this lib, or if it is a native lib, then reinstall python, and when that doesn't work, maybe try a different python version, *3.5* f.e..

Comment: This answer is hard to read. You might want to consider breaking it into two or three paragraphs.

Comment: Don't start an answer with "as I don't have enough reputation to comment..." This actually looks like a reasonable start to an answer, and partial answers are okay. But if you really do want to leave a comment, then you just have to be okay with not leaving it - answer boxes are *not* an okay place to put comments just because you don't have the rep to comment properly. Since this is a decent partial answer, it's probably fine, but starting your answer by commenting on your lack of reputation is likely to get it flagged as "Not an answer."

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! :D